# Why do I get the IllegalAccsessError?

Tags: java, jar, minecraft

I am currently programming an automatic Updater that downloads the newest version of my plugin from GitHub.
I got the Plugin to disable, I could replace it and now I wanna enable it, but I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class de.pixel.woolbattle.game.Lobby$1 from class de.pixel.woolbattle.game.Lobby, which seems really odd to me. My Discord: DasBabyPixel#3070
```

The line that the error points to is line 30 in my 'Lobby' class. There is a `private static int deathTimer = Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(...)`
I tried to make the "private" to "protected" or "public", but none of them worked

```
private static int deathTimer = Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(Main.getPlugin(Main.class), new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Main.getGameState().getLobby() != null && Main.getGameState().getLobby().isEnabled()) {
                if (isPaused)
                    return;
                for (Player p : Main.getPlayers()) {
                    YamlConfiguration cfg = Main.getPlugin().getConfig("lobby");
                    if (p.getLocation().getBlockY() < cfg.getInt("deathheight")) {
                        p.teleport(Main.getGameState().getLobby().getSpawn());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, 10, 10);
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class de.pixel.woolbattle.game.Lobby$1 from class de.pixel.woolbattle.game.Lobby
        at de.pixel.woolbattle.game.Lobby.<clinit>(Lobby.java:30) ~[?:?]
        at de.pixel.woolbattle.Main.onEnable(Main.java:91) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:357) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:317) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:414) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:378) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:333) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:263) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:525) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_221]
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Is the Main.class is imported correctly with **your** Main class?</s>

```
Main.getPlugin(Main.class)
```

Instead of this, you can create an instance in your main class to make coding easier and more safely.

EDIT: This misbehavior thing it should be avoided. As if we declares a field with the type of Main class this will cases to cache into memory as an unnecessary stored field. Instead of `Main.getPlugin` you should use `JavaPlugin` abstract class to get your plugin object and with proper static access.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that the problem was the jar overriding with embeds. I've programmed an external plugin that Downloads the APIs and the main Plugin, if that failes, it copies them from an internal storage path. And when the Server stops, I just delete all the downloaded Plugins, so i can re-download them without the same odd embed error.